# updating postgres jsonb column

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have below json string in my table column which is of type jsonb,

```
{
    "abc": 1,
    "def": 2
}
```

i want to remove the "abc" key from it and insert "mno" with some default value. i followed the below approcach for it.

```
UPDATE books SET books_desc = books_desc - 'abc';
UPDATE books SET books_desc = jsonb_set(books_desc, '{mno}', '5');
```

and it works.

Now i have another table with json as below,

```
{
    "a": {
        "abc": 1,
        "def": 2
    },
    "b": {
        "abc": 1,
        "def": 2
    }
}
```

Even in this json, i want to do the same thing. take out "abc" and introduce "mno" with some default value. Please help me to achieve this.

The keys "a" and "b" are dynamic and can change. But the values for "a" and "b"  will always have same keys but values may change. 
I  need a generic logic.

**Requirement 2:**

abc:true should get converted to xyz:1.

abc:false should get converted to xyz:0.

Comment: i wonder why you choose for JSON here? As the example data is more easy to be stored in SQL tables to be selected, updated or deleted. .. As it looks that JSON is a bit misplaced to be used here.

Comment: But thats the kind of json i am recieving from the external module.

Comment: Fair enough.. Can you read [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) for providing better example data and expected results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=2b3ee77c7f8ed080d87db16b03e9c52f)

Because of a possible variety of your JSON keys it might be complicated to generate a common query. This is because you need to give the path within the `json_set()` function. But without actual values it would be hard.

A simple work-around is using the `regexp_replace()` function on the text representation of the JSON string to replace the relevant objects.

```
UPDATE my_table
SET my_data = 
    regexp_replace(my_data::text, '"abc"\s*:\s*\d+', '"mno":5', 'g')::jsonb
```

Comment: It works. Thanks for the help. I have also answered for the requirement 2 which i mentioned in the question. Please go through my answer and provide your comments

Answer (score 1):

For added requirement 2:

I wrote the below query based on already given solution:

```
UPDATE books
SET book_info = 
    regexp_replace(book_info::text, '"abc"\s*:\s*true', '"xyz":1', 'g')::jsonb; 

UPDATE books
SET book_info = 
    regexp_replace(book_info::text, '"abc"\s*:\s*false', '"xyz":0', 'g')::jsonb;
```